# Anyone used approvaltests with specflow?

Tags: specflow, approval-tests

Has anyone used Specflow with [ApprovalTests](http://approvaltests.sourceforge.net/)?

I find it limiting that you can only approve one file per NUnit test and therefore each scenario can only have one approved file. This is the case even if you use scenario outlines.

This means I usually have to concatenate files and approve one large file which repesents the results of lots of independent tests.

I wonder has anyone found a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the creator of approvaltests. I haven't used specflow myself yet, but the solution you are looking for would reside in the Namer.

A little background:
Approve() uses 3 pieces

1. a namer - this gets the ***.***. received & approved file
2. a writer - this outputs to that said file
3. a reporter - this is called on failure

Right now the namers only use the class & method name to determine the file name which is why they cause a problem when you want more than one file per method.

you need to extend the namer to use more inputs (i'm guessing here but)  class, method & scenario.

I'd be happy to pair w/you via skype to create the namer.

Comment: Yes that would be cool I am mcapodici on skype. I am on now for an hour or so. In general I am on from about EST 7pm - 1am.

Comment: I ran into the same problem trying to use BDDfy, or even before that with plain old unit tests.  I would like to be able to have each call to Verify be unique.  I just saw another post about using the NamerFactory to accomplish that, so I may play around with it.

Comment: @MartinCapodici did you came up with something?

Comment: @DavidWalser whoa! That was almost 9 years ago. IIRC Llewellyn did commit something, maybe grep the git log for Oct 11 from https://github.com/approvals/ApprovalTests.Net/commits/master :-)

Comment: any other opinions after 13 years? i can go with specflow/cucumber/gherkin only.... to me approval tests are embedded in gherkin conceptually